# Javascript compare time periods and get overlapping

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a timeline with visjs.
As in the picture below (the blue bars) I have these three time periods and would like to have the black bars as a result.

[Time Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnGWS.png)

But I can't find any way to solve this?
I have the times in this format:

```
{ start: "2021-09-02 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-05 02:00:00"}    ​
{ start: "2021-09-03 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-04 02:00:00"}   
{ start: "2021-09-03 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-03 20:00:00"}
```

My desired result:

```
{ start: "2021-09-02 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-03 02:00:00", load: '1/3'}  
{ start: "2021-09-03 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-03 20:00:00", load: '3/3'}
.
.
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const intervals = [
  { start: "2021-09-02 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-05 02:00:00" },
  { start: "2021-09-03 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-04 02:00:00" },
  { start: "2021-09-03 02:00:00", end: "2021-09-03 20:00:00" },
];

// Calculate period delimiters and overlap counts
const delimiters = [...new Set(intervals.flatMap(interval => [interval.start, interval.end]))].sort();
const periods = delimiters.map(delimiter => ({delimiter, overlaps: 0}));
for (let i = 0; i < periods.length - 1; i += 1) {
  for (const interval of intervals) {
    if (interval.start <= periods[i].delimiter && periods[i + 1].delimiter <= interval.end) {
      periods[i].overlaps += 1;
    }
  }
}

// Print result
periods.forEach((period, i) => {
  console.log(period.delimiter);
  if (i < periods.length - 1) {
    console.log(`    ${period.overlaps}/${intervals.length}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you're supposed to start objects with `[` and not `{`

Comment: its the snippet from the console.log

Comment: If you're using objects, then start with `[` not `{` it's not a function